# What happens if input current of 2A is given to a L7805 rated of 1.5A?

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, voltage-regulator

I have used a L7805 to regulate a 12V to 5V where the regulator is rated of 1.5A and the input that I am providing is of 2A.  The regulator gets hot. The only solution I found is to increase the width of the track of input line and also use thermal vias to carry away the heat.

Is there is any other way to solve this issue?

Here I cannot use any heatsink or any other cooling technique.

Comment: Apart from the 7805 being faulty, it will only draw 2A if the output is wanting to draw 2A. If this were the case, then the 7805 should shut down. Being a linear reg, the 7805 wastes the excess voltage as heat. You can estimate the temp rise by (vin -vout) times Amps. This gives you the number of Watts being wasted. The 7805 has a spec that tells you the number of degrees C the temp will rise per Watt. At a guess I think it is something like 70C/W. Do the sums. If it gets too hot, then you’ll need a heatsink. Or use a switchmode supply.

Comment: I agree that a 7805 can be fed from a car battery that can produce 600A (!) or more.

Comment: 12V - 5V = 7V at 1.5A would mean 10.5W of heat to dissipate.  Drive the 7805 with a lower voltage or use a switchmode power supply.

Answer (score 3):

The provided input does not matter. What matters is how much current the load consumes at 5V.

The regulator can accept 12V input, and it can provide 5V at up to 1.5A.

But it can't do all that simultaneously. As it is a linear regulator, the need to drop 12V to 5V at 1.5A means the chip has to dissipate 10.5W, which is so much it likely is not possible even with a heatsink and forced air cooling which you already said can't be implemented.

You can't make the circuit work with a 7805 linear regulator as it is just a wrong type of component for this task, you need a switching mode DC/DC converter instead of a linear regulator.

Comment: _"... has to dissipate 10.5W, which is so much it likely is not possible even with a heatsink and forced air cooling"_ - 10.5W from a TO-220 into a heatsink with forced air cooling sounds easily doable to me. Wasteful, sure, but very possible.

Comment: Transistors packages in TO-126 can dissipate 10W with good heat sinking. TO-220 won’t even notice if you do it right, but you need either lots of airflow or lots of metal.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing which brand or version of the 7805 you have, there's no way to know the specifics of how it will act.

Many 7805 have internal current limiters. And thermal shutdown.

One brand's datasheet says that the current limiter triggers at around 2.4 amps. Another one's says that thermal shutdown happens when the internal die gets to 150 degrees C.

You are dropping (12V - 5V) * 2A = 14 watts of power as waste heat. Without proper heatsinking, the IC will go into thermal shutdown, which works by current limiting as well. Active cooling is pretty much required at this wattage.

**Your only options if you can't use heatsinking or cooling, is to change your design.**

1. Change your load so it's smaller.
2. Change your regulator. At 10W output from 24W input, your at 41 percent efficiency. Any common switching regulator will be 70 to 90% efficient so only like 1.5 watts wasted. There's 3 pin drop in 7805 replacement modules.
3. Change to a better linear regulator package like a TO-3 and bond it to a metal case. You will still be wasting 14 watts in heat so I doubt you can find much better without better heatsinking.
4. Parallel regulators. Spread the load across multiple 7805 regulators so each only only handles 0.5 amp, and thus only waste 25% of the heat. You still have 14 watts wasted but spread evenly.

The switching regulator is your best option.

Comment: @ThePhoton scriveners error, the TI lm7805 says 150 C junction temp.

Comment: Have an upvote for using the word "scrivener"

Answer (score 1):

Regulating 12V to 5V with a linear regulator is a very inefficient method to do the job. With 7 volts dropped across the regulator more power goes into producing heat than actually is delivered to the 5 volt load. You should consider a change of strategy and find a suitable switching regulator component or module to use instead.

We also need to straighten out what appears to be a misunderstanding on your part regarding the current capabilities and flows. When using a regulator like a 7805 the current taken from the source, passing through the regulator and subsequently going into the load will be pretty much the same (neglecting the couple of milliamps used internal to the regulator itself). It is the load that sets the amount of current in this path. If the load is 1.5A or less the current from the source will be no more. You could have a source capable of supplying 166A and the current drawn will be more more that what the load requires. Obviously you need to manage the load design to stay within the 1.5A capability of the 7805 AND properly manage the heat generated by the 7V drop across the regulator. At 1.5V the power being thrown to heat in the regulator is 7V * 1.5A = 10.5 watts. You will need a suitable heat sink / cooling system.